# Placement of "more": Which one do native speakers say?

Tags: sentence-construction

- I need to read more books to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing.
- I need to read books more to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing.
- I need to do more reading to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing.

If none of these is correct, would you please help me use the right sentence?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are asking. Are you wondering if there is a difference in meaning between the sentences? Are you asking which of the sentences are gramatically correct? Are you asking something else?

Answer (score 1):

> More reading will help me write more logically.
>
> Reading more will help me write more logically.
>
> Great writers are also voracious readers.

Notice that these suggestions are much shorter than the original post's examples.  Usually, a short sentence (that makes the same point) is better than a long sentence.  Also, there are some standard patterns for "logical writing".  These examples use two of those patterns.

The original examples use several "helper verbs".  In these examples, the "helper verbs" do not add any meaning.  Eliminating them makes the sentences clearer.

The following sentence flows even better than the first two examples in this answer, because the two halves are even more parallel.  Unfortunately, it changes the meaning.  It leaves out the idea of "writing better" or "writing more logically". Instead, it just says that you will write more text:

> Reading more will help me write more.

Answer (score 0):

Either of:

> 1) I need **to read** more books to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing.
>   3) I need **to do more reading** to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing.

are fine and essentially mean the same thing. However in

> I need **to read books *more*** to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing.

is incorrect because **more** is used as a quantifier:

> I need to read books **more** to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing **than** to increase my vocabulary.

Comment: I would disagree; "more" is not being used as a comparative, but still as a quantifier, with "more *often*" being the fuller phrasing. And indeed your suggested replacement is grammatically awkward; it should be "I need to read books more to help myself develop a sense of logic in my writing than to increase my vocabulary." The comma does not belong and "rather" is redundant with "more" + "than".

Comment: @NathanTuggy Right you are. I edited my answer. The "rather" was an afterthought, but you are right it is not necessary.